# Problema expresiones regular JS

Tags: javascript

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo" />
        <div id="tituloPost"></div>
<textarea class="form-control" name="contenido" id="contenido" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje aquÃ­" ></textarea>
        <div id="mensaje"></div>
```

Y el boton

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Validar campos" onclick="return validarCampos()" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Publicar nuevo tema</button>
```

Tengo esta función que me comprueba dos `input`

```
function validarCampos(){
    var valido = true;
    var titulo = document.getElementById("titulo").value;
    var testTitulo = /^[\W\s\w]{1,100}$/i;

    var mensaje = document.getElementById("contenido").value;
    var testMensaje = /^[\W\s\w]{1,2000}$/i;

    if (testTitulo.test(titulo)) {
      valido = true;    
    } else{
      valido = false;
      document.getElementById("tituloPost").innerHTML = "Este campo no debe de estar vacÃ­o ni superar los 100 caracteres";

    }

     if (testMensaje.test(mensaje)) {
       valido = true;
    } else {
      valido = false;
      document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = "Este campo no debe de estar vacÃ­o ni superar los 2000 caracteres";
    }

    return valido;
  }
```

El problema esta en que cuando uno de los dos campos esta relleno y el otro vacio me manda la informacion y no deberia de ser asi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes esta en la funcion, realmente no verifique la expresion regular si esta bien echa, pero por lo que preguntas el error esta aca mira:

En 2 momentos distintos preguntas sobre los campos lo cual a cada sentencia if modifica el valor de 'valido'.
Y lo que debe estar sucediendo es que quizas, tu primer campo esta vacio, pero el segundo esta completo, por lo cual, en tu segundo if a valido le das 'true' y esto es lo que estas haciendo mal en tu funcion.
Una solucion puede ser esta:

```
        function validarCampos(){
        var titulo = document.getElementById("titulo").value;
        var testTitulo = /^[\W\s\w]{1,100}$/i;

        var mensaje = document.getElementById("contenido").value;
        var testMensaje = /^[\W\s\w]{1,2000}$/i;

        if (!testTitulo.test(titulo)) {
          document.getElementById("tituloPost").innerHTML = "Este campo no debe de estar vacÃ­o ni superar los 100 caracteres";
    return false;

        }

         if (!testMensaje.test(mensaje)) {
          document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = "Este campo no debe de estar vacÃ­o ni superar los 2000 caracteres";
    return false;
        }
    document.getElementById("tituloPost").innerHTML ="";
document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML ="";
        return true;
      }
```

De todas formas ,verifica que este correcto y seguramente se puede mejorar.

Comment: Vale me funciona, pero y si quiero que cuando este bien se me quite el mensaje de error que aparece debajo @LcsGrz

Comment: Ahi agrege la correcion que mencionaste, es fea, pero debe funcionar

Answer (score 0):

A mi me paso hace poco lo mismo, lo mejor, es que hagas varias funciones, te voy a dejar un codigo mio, que controla un formulario.

```
 function iniciar() {
    document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener('click', validar, false);
}

function validarNumSocio() {
    var numeroSocio = document.getElementById("numeroSocio");
    if /**/ (numeroSocio.value == "") {
        numeroSocio.className = "erroneo";
        numeroSocio.focus();
        alert("El numero no puede estar vacio");
        return false;
    } else if (numeroSocio.value > 999 || numeroSocio.value <= 99) {
        numeroSocio.className = "erroneo";
        numeroSocio.focus();
        alert("El numero debe estar entre 99 y 999");
        return false;
    } else if (isNaN(numeroSocio.value)) {
        numeroSocio.className = "erroneo";
        numeroSocio.focus();
        alert("Debe de ser un numero");
        return false
    } else {
        numeroSocio.className = "";
        return true;
    }
}

function validarDni() {
    var dni = document.getElementById("dni");
    if (dni.value.length == 0) {
        dni.className = "erroneo";
        dni.focus();
        alert("El dni no puede estar vacio");
        return false;
    } else if (dni.value.length != 9) {
        dni.className = "erroneo";
        alert("El dni tiene que tener 9 cifras");
        dni.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        dni.className = "";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Es un ejemplo, ahora pon todas las funciones que quieras. Y por ultimo, esta funcion, que es la que te comprueba que todas son verdaderas.

```
function validar(e) {
    if (validarNumSocio() && validarDni() && validarFecha() && validarNombre() && validarprimerApellido() && validarsegundoApellido() && validarLocalidad()) {
        crearUsu();
        return true;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Este ejemplo, se va parando en cada funcion para decir que esta mal ese campo, espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo.